# How to upload image using access token?

Tags: php, facebook, access-token

I am creating this url from jquery with an access token

```
www.mysite.com/xyz.php?access_token=valid_access_token&id=1
```

and to upload photo I am using this code in `xyz.php`

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
            'appId' => 'my_app_id',
            'secret' => 'my_app_secret',
        ));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

 $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'my_message');
                copy($image, 'tmp/file.jpeg');
                $args['image'] = '@' . realpath('tmp/file.jpeg');
                $data = $facebook->api('me/photos', 'post', $args);
                unlink('tmp/file.jpeg');
```

but it doesn't work. I get this error

```
Uncaught OAuthException: An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
```

I have created a access token. why am I getting this error?
how can I use the accessToken(which is in my url) in my code to upload image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get the user's access token to perform any action on behalf of the user. Try using the following code...

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId' => 'my_app_id',
  'secret' => 'my_app_secret',
));

// Get User ID
$user = $facebook->getUser();

if (!$user)
{
    // User is not logged in or hasn't added the application!

    $login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'scope' => 'publish_stream,user_photos,photo_upload',
    ));

    die('<script>top.window.location = "' . $login_url . '";</script>');
}

$facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$args = array('message' => 'my_message');
                copy($image, 'tmp/file.jpeg');
                $args['image'] = '@' . realpath('tmp/file.jpeg');
                $data = $facebook->api('me/photos', 'post', $args);
                unlink('tmp/file.jpeg');
```